# Zlib in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, zlib, void

I am following [these instructions](http://tpgit.github.com/UnOfficialLeptDocs/vs2008/building-image-libraries.html#building-zlib) to test the zlibStat library with testzlib. When I try to build testzlib, it throws the following error in [**testzlib.c**](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/testzlib/testzlib.c), Line: 167, Char:43:

> `IntelliSense: argument of type "unsigned char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "void **"`

Is it a specification change in C11, a bug in VC 11 or a bad code?

Is there a workaround? I tried changing `unsigned char* FilePtr;` to `void* FilePtr;`, but then the *assignment operator* throws the error on Line 200. Any thoughts?

## Solution

I followed Icepack's answer. Then I got an error on line 141, so I changed it to `*pFilePtr=(unsigned char*)ptr;`. Hopefully zlib guys would update their code accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit conversion doesn't work with double indirection. Converting `char*` to `void*` is ok, but `char**` to `void**` isn't. See here for more details: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html

Try replacing the `ReadFileMemory` signature with `ReadFileMemory(const char* filename,long* plFileSize,unsigned char** pFilePtr)`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I had to change line 141. See the updated solution in my post above.